# when I run vagrant ssh the screen just hangs on the system status report

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

```
PS C:\Users\l> vagrant←[100m ssh←[100m
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-162-generic x

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sun Sep 10 20:11:49 UTC 2023

  System load:  0.0               Processes:               1
  Usage of /:   7.0% of 38.70GB   Users logged in:         0
  Memory usage: 22%               IPv4 address for enp0s3: 1
  Swap usage:   0%

 * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. L
   just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s cl

   https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enable
0 updates can be applied immediately.
3 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu
New release '22.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
Last login: Sun Sep 10 20:01:20 2023 from 10.0.2.2
```

Comment: This "hang" scenario happened to me when I was using Git Bash. I tried Windows CMD CLI and got through the "hang" and to the shell prompt! Then I tried Windows Powershell right after and got through as well. Right after that, I tried Git Bash again and it also got through. All that was after many tries and closing out the Git Bash CLI window and all I got was that "hang."